# Compilation error using Hamcrest everyItem()

Tags: java, generics, junit, hamcrest

I'm trying to use `hasKey()` on `everyItem()` in Hamcrest but I am getting the following compilation error:

```
error: no suitable method found for assertThat(List<Map<String,Object>>,Matcher<Iterable<Map<? extends String,?>>>)
        assertThat(data, everyItem(hasKey("index")));
        ^
    method Assert.<T#1>assertThat(T#1,Matcher<? super T#1>) is not applicable
      (actual argument Matcher<Iterable<Map<? extends String,?>>> cannot be converted to Matcher<? super List<Map<String,Object>>> by method invocation conversion)
    method Assert.<T#2>assertThat(String,T#2,Matcher<? super T#2>) is not applicable
      (cannot instantiate from arguments because actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
  where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
    T#1 extends Object declared in method <T#1>assertThat(T#1,Matcher<? super T#1>)
    T#2 extends Object declared in method <T#2>assertThat(String,T#2,Matcher<? super T#2>)
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 error
```

Here is a simple JUnit test that recreates the error:

```
package test;

import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import static org.hamcrest.collection.IsMapContaining.hasKey;
import static org.hamcrest.core.Every.everyItem;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

public class Test {

    @Test
    public void test(){
        List<Map<String, Object>> data = new ArrayList<>();
        Map<String,Object> element = new HashMap<>();
        element.put("index", 1);
        data.add(element);

        assertThat(data, everyItem(hasKey("index")));
    }



}
```

- Java 1.7
- Hamcrest 1.3
- JUnit 4.11

Does anyone know how to resolve this compilation error?

Comment: Please list your import statements too.

Comment: (Don't have an environment on hand) does adding a cast for `data` work? i.e. `assertThat((Iterable<Map<String,Object>>)data, everyItem(hasKey("index")));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a case of nested generics.

`data` is currently declared as a `List<Map<String, Object>>`, while [`everyItem(hasKey("index"))`](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#everyItem%28org.hamcrest.Matcher%29) is inferred as returning a `Matcher<Iterable<Map<? extends String, ?>>>`.

As the compilation error message states

> The method `assertThat(T, Matcher<? super T>)` in the type `Assert` is not
>   applicable for the arguments (`List<Map<String,Object>>,
>   Matcher<Iterable<Map<? extends String,?>>>`)

This boils down to [`hasKey`](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#hasKey%28K%29) having a return type of `Map<? extends T, ?` rather than `Map<T, ?>`, but there's probably a good reason for that.

Fortunately, your code is simple enough that you can declare `data` as

```
List<Map<? extends String, ?>> data = new ArrayList<>();
```

and have the code compile.

Comment: I tried your line of code replacing the first line of the asker's test code. It did not compile for me.

Comment: @Jazzepi Works fine for me in Eclipse with Java 7, and in [ideone](http://ideone.com/7uR1Qc).

Comment: Thanks, this works. The compilation message was clear enough I was just having problems finding the right combination of parenthesis and angle brackets to make it compile; didn't consider being _less_ specific about my known types.